# How to make wishlist items persistent even after adding to cart

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, wishlist

I want items in my wishlist to remain there even if I add it to cart. I am completely new to magento and as far I have understood it is doint it using observer. I have tried doing it by removing following code from config.xml

```
<checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
    <observers>
        <wishlist>
            <class>wishlist/observer</class>
            <method>processAddToCart</method>
        </wishlist>
    </observers>
</checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
```

But still it gets removed from wishlist. Where is that part implemented in magento?

Answer (score 1):

To disable this event you can add your own module with the following config:

```
<global>
    <events>
        <checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
            <observers>
                <wishlist>
                    <type>disabled</type>
                </wishlist>
            </observers>
        </checkout_cart_add_product_complete>
    </events>
</global>
```

Make sure that after adding this you clear the config cache.

Comment: Tried it. Still not working.